# Looping a password checker in C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, loops

I'm trying to create a password checker.

My idea was to have a `bool` return type method with a `string` parameter which would be the user's input. If the `string` fulfills all the conditions, the method would return `true`. Otherwise it should return `false` and loop from the start (take another input from the user to check the password again).

Problem is, even though I got all the conditions that I wanted to have right, I can't get it to loop every time a condition is `false`. I've tried to do it with `for`, etc., but it doesn't seem to work. I assume the problem is in the user input (I'm either putting it somewhere that's wrong or something like that) but at this point I'm out of ideas.

If you have an answer, please explain it to me instead of just giving me some code so I can understand where did I go wrong.

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace BeginnerProjects
{
    class PasswordCreator
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            string passLengthReq = "Password length should be 8 symbols or more.";
            string passUppercaseReq = "Password should contain at least one uppercase letter.";
            string passDigitReq = "Password should contain at least one digit.";

            Console.WriteLine("Please insert your desired password, the password has the following requirements:");
            Console.WriteLine($"{passLengthReq}\n{passUppercaseReq}\n{passDigitReq}");

            string chosenPass = Console.ReadLine();
            
            do
            {

                IsPassCorrect(chosenPass);
                Console.ReadLine();

            } 
            while (IsPassCorrect(chosenPass) == false);
            
            static bool IsPassCorrect(string chosenPass)
            {

                // Checks for Null
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(chosenPass))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Password is empty!");
                    return false;

                }

                // Checks for Length
                else if (chosenPass.Length < 8)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Your password is too short, it contains {chosenPass.Length} characters!");
                    return false;
                }

                // Checks for Number Present
                else if (!chosenPass.Any(char.IsNumber))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Error, your password doesn't contain a number!");
                    return false;
                }

                // Checks for Decimal Present
                else if (chosenPass.Any(char.IsDigit))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Error, your password contains a decimal!");
                    return false;
                }
                // Checks for Uppercase Letter
                else if (!chosenPass.Any(char.IsUpper))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Error, your password doesn't contain an uppercase letter!");
                    return false;
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Your password is valid!");
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Slightly weird. It must contain a number but not contain digit? So only Roman numerals and fractions allowed??

Comment: Console.ReadLine() by itself just waits for an enter and ignores any typed text. You need to assign its result to that chosenPass variable

Comment: @Charlieface About the digit thing, I was trying for it to check if there was a `float` (which should give an error) and after trying it with `TryParse` it didn't work for me because it was also detecting `int` as a `float`, so then I tried using LinQ after reading another post (and it isn't working either).

Comment: Maybe `float.TryParse(chosenPass, out var result) && result % 1 != 0` But to be honest, not sure why you think these passwords are bad, that's a separate discussion. See [Correct Horse Battery Staple](https://xkcd.com/936/)

Comment: @Charlieface It's just a beginner project that I was doing to get better at C#, I'm not really trying to create a password checker with a perfect logic or anything :p Thanks for the modulus fix to check if there's a decimal present I didn't thought about that and it worked perfectly :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take this part:

```
string chosenPass = Console.ReadLine();

do
{

    IsPassCorrect(chosenPass);
    Console.ReadLine();

} 
while (IsPassCorrect(chosenPass) == false);
```

And change it to:

```
string chosenPass;

do
{
    chosenPass = Console.ReadLine();
} 
while (IsPassCorrect(chosenPass) == false);
```

Now the loop will always prompt the user before checking the password, and keep doing so until `IsPassCorrect(chosenPass)` returns true.

You can simplify `IsPassCorrect(chosenPass) == false` if desired:

```
string chosenPass;

do
{
    chosenPass = Console.ReadLine();
} 
while (!IsPassCorrect(chosenPass));
```

Comment: That worked perfectly, thanks for the quick help :D

Comment: @Nyxnik If this answer solved the problem, you can click `√` to mark it as an answer.